# How to show another list_display inside fieldsets?

Tags: django

When clicking on original list_display item I want it to show another list_display(containing of models that have ForeignKey to original item) instead of normal fieldsets.

I can get it working but only with inlines, is it possible to display it as another list_display?

I am using Django Suit to get tabs:

```
class KWInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Url
    list_display = ('title', 'url', 'pda', 'upa')
    extra = 0
    suit_classes = 'suit-tab suit-tab-cities'

class KWAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):

    resource_class = KWResource
    list_display = ('Keyword', 'searches', 'cpc', 'comp'...)
    inlines = [KWInline]

    fieldsets = [
    (None, {
        'classes': ('suit-tab suit-tab-cities',),
        'fields': ['Keyword', 'searches', 'cpc']}),
     ... .... ...
    suit_form_tabs = (('general', 'General'), ('cities', 'Cities'),
                       ('flag', 'Flag'), ('info', 'Info on tabs'))
```

I tried changing `admin.TabularInline` to normal admin and get expected error(calling inlines without proper class inheritance)

It looks like this, any ideas on how to change inlines to list_display?:

[image]